# Rotating features with multiple geometries in one layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, features, rotate, angles

I have a layer containing several small square geometries in QGIS. I want to tilt these ones by one to the same angle. So I wrote the following Python code for that, but it does not work properly. Could you please give me some suggestions for improvement?

```py
#import processing

layer_name = "my_layer"

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

features = layer.getFeatures()

for feature in features:
  geometry = feature.geometry()
  center = geometry.centroid().asPoint()
  rotated_geometry = geometry.rotate(33, center)
  feature.setGeometry(rotated_geometry)
  layer.updateFeature(feature)

layer.updateExtents()
```

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 12):

There are several things that I would improve:

- do not forget to start/[`startEditing`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a1cb9fe1007c931a0e78195607ace518e), end/[`endEditCommand()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a58406bdbb6a5e6361e3a68635f2e4b87), and commit/[`commitChanges()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a93f0ed3e36e1842b16c931b969518db4) editings
- use the [`setGeometry()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#ae6c4c7a5c40d420c95285ce072c24307) method properly, otherwise the result of it will be just [`GeometryOperationResult.Success`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#a2231cf0dcd15b05248b74439d64dc06e)
- make your code homogeneous

  ```py
   layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon")[0]
   ...
       geometry.rotate(33, center)
  ```

  or

  ```py
   layer_name = "polygon"
   angle = 33

   layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
   ...
       geometry.rotate(angle, center)
  ```
- use `for feature in layer.getFeatures()` in one line
- import only classes that are deployed, no need for the `import processing`
- the [`hasGeometry()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#ad08c562ec979020d21a7b0dc40681b7e) method of the `QgsFeature` class can be useful

In the end, your code may look as follows:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("my_layer")[0]

layer.startEditing()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    while feature.hasGeometry():
        geometry = feature.geometry()
        center = geometry.centroid().asPoint()
        geometry.rotate(33, center)
        feature.setGeometry(geometry)
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
        break
    
layer.endEditCommand()
layer.commitChanges()
```

*Note: **Remember that applied changes can not be undone***.

Another approach can be found in the references.

---

**References:**

- [Rotating features in memory layer using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368660/rotating-features-in-memory-layer-using-pyqgis)

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion @Taras. It worked fine and did exactly what I wanted it to do perfectly!

Comment: @Is.Ballad please mark the question accepted!

Comment: Is the `endEditCommand()` really necessary? I have never seen it used and the `commitChanges()` specifically has a `stopEditing` parameter. And if you are going to commit the changes straight away why bother manually stopping the edit block, even the `qgis.core.edit(layer)` with statement block of qgis calls `commitChanges()` directly. also why do a `while break` where a simple `if` would do ?